# Is smell a spiritual sense?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, smell, kedusha-holiness, korbanos-ketores-prayers

I once learned that smell is not like the other senses of the body. That it is a sort-of holy sense. One of the reasons was that while the other senses are somewhat necessary for the body, smell is for the soul. I have actually heard that the Cohanim used incenses in the Mishkan. Is this a common concept in judaism?

Comment: The kohanim also ate meat/bread, lit candles, and arranged for music in the mikdash

Comment: I know that.. I'm just talking about something they taught me, and I want to know the sources of it. No need for sarcastic answers.

Comment: I agree there is no need for sarcastic answers. If you knew what I said, why did you use the fact that incense is burnt in the mikdash as evidence for your claim that olfaction is somehow uniquely spiritual?

Comment: I immediately thought of the havdalah service at the conclusion of the Sabbath. A spice mixture is passed around the congregation who take a sniff. I believe the intent is to have a final reminder of the joy of Shabbat as the work week begins. So in that "sense", I would say. There is something spiritual about "smell"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Berachos 43b:

> איזהו דבר שהנשמה נהנית ממנו ואין הגוף נהנה ממנו, הוי אומר זה הריח
>
> What is a thing that the soul benefits from and the body does not? That is the sense of smell